# pass member function to QtConcurrent run()

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to pass a member function to QtConcurrent::run()

I have tried to do it like so:

```
GDALDriver *poNITFDriver;
future = QtConcurrent::run(poNITFDriver,&GDALDriver::CreateCopy, pszDstFilename, poDataset, FALSE,  papszOptions, pfnProgress, NULL);
```

but I get a slew of errors regarding no matching function call.

This was the original call:

poNITFDriver->CreateCopy(pszDstFilename, poDataset, FALSE,  papszOptions, pfnProgress, NULL);

What am I doing wrong? Can run() accept that many arguments?

This is the error I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to run(GDALDriver*&, GDALDataset* (GDALDriver::*)(const char*, GDALDataset*, int, char**, int (*)(double, const char*, void*), void*), const char**, GDALDataset**, bool, char***, int (**)(double, const char*, void*), NULL)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass a pointer of the object as the first argument and the address of the method as the second argument (then follow it by any other arguments).

Have a look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) documentation. Have a look at the sections:

- [Using Member Functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions)
- [Using Lambda Functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-lambda-functions)

Specifically, you can use `boost::bind()` or `std::tr1::bind()` to bind a number of arguments to a function when called. There are number of reasons for doing this:

- To call a function that takes more than 5 arguments.
- To simplify calling a function with constant arguments.
- Changing the order of arguments.

I think you have more than 5 parameters being passed there.

Comment: edited to reflect that the first argument IS a pointer to the object

Comment: @Derek: Please check the updated answer, I think the documentation has the detail of what you need to do.